# Searching for a specific string in TinyMCE

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm creating a short-code generator for the WordPress Add/Edit Post/Page screen.

I want to make sure that there does not exist more than one short-code in the same post/page. So I added an `onclick`  function for the button so that whether there already exist a short-code, could be checked.

**How do I go on doing this?**

I searched around the TinyMCE API and the closest I got was the [tinymce.Formatter.match](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Formatter.match) method. But there's no example on this page. I don't really think that this has anything to do with the content search anyway.

Another way would be to simply use the [getContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent) method and run javascript code against it. But I guess this wouldn't be the best option if there's something built-in for this already.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what you mean by the term "short-code".
But i guess it is a string you can find using getContent-Method.

There are several other ways to search the editor content.
Since tinymce editor is rendered inside an iframe and is indeed real html code you can use all regular DOM-Methods of your browser. There are even some additional DOM-Methods provided in `tiny_mce/classes/dom/DOMUtils.js`.